# Get line separated text from element with <br> tags from cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to get contact information through cypress and compare it with database. So I need to split the details and get Title, First Name, Last Name, Country... etc.

But the text contain in a single div and it has been separated using `<br>` tag.

Then I have tried to get the text as follows:

```
cy.xpath('element xpath').invoke('text').then((AddressLineText) => {
        cy.log(AddressLineText);
});
```

Flowing is the invoked text and it has been connected the line texts without even a space. Due to that I'm unable to split by space or /n.

[image: Cypress Log for invoke text]

Bellow is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="address">
    Mr. Test User
    <br>
    Testing Services Ltd
    <br>
    Britannia House
    <br>
    Rushmills
    <br>
    NN4 7YB, Northampton
    <br>
    Northamptonshire
    <br>
    United Kingdom
</div>
```

How to isolate each lines according to this scenario.

Comment: If it is a String you could just `AddressLineText.replaceAll('<div class="address">', '').replaceAll('</div>', '').split('<br>')` to get an array of the informations.

Comment: The invoked text not having html tags to split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<br>` tags become newlines after text extract

```js
cy.get('.address')
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => text.split('\n'))                // split by newline
  .then(texts => texts.map(text => text.trim()))  // trim whitespace
  .then(texts => texts.filter(text => text))     // remove empty
  .then(texts => {
    console.log(texts)
  })
})
```

prints

```js
["Mr. Test User", "Testing Services Ltd", "Britannia House", "Rushmills", "NN4 7YB, Northampton", "Northamptonshire", "United Kingdom"]
```

---

**Node.TEXT_NODE**

Extracting the text nodes of the div is better if the content is more complicated.

- use `.childNodes` to get all `<br>` and texts within address `<div>`
- filter children by node type to remove `<br>`
- get node values and trim spaces and newlines

```js
cy.get('.address')
  .then($el => $el[0].childNodes)  
  .then(children => [...children].filter(child => child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE))
  .then(textNodes => textNodes.map(textNode => textNode.nodeValue.trim()))
  .then(texts => {
    console.log(texts)
  })
```

prints

```js
["Mr. Test User", "Testing Services Ltd", "Britannia House", "Rushmills", "NN4 7YB, Northampton", "Northamptonshire", "United Kingdom"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Electron. The second solution is perfectly working for the scenario...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each()` to get all your individual texts printed. One line for each text in the test runner logs.

```
cy.xpath('element xpath').each(($ele) => {
   cy.log($ele.text());
});
```

Comment: I've tried this and it logged all null records, I'm thinking its because it has only <br>, not inside <br> text </br>

Comment: Can you share your html DOM. The issue is with the xpath.